# Why methods at the base class with the same name (not signature) must be called with full name from inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Its a theoretical question just to understand better why the following scenario is not supported.

Check out the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}

    void f(int x){ printf("A::f(x)\r\n"); }
    void g(int x){ printf("A::g(x)\r\n"); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){}

    void f(){ f(5); } // <- does not compile
    void f(){ A::f(5); } // <- compiles
    void f(){ g(5); } // <- compiles
};
```

Class B inherits class A.

When B::f() calls A::f() by not using its full name (i.e. void f(){ f(5); } ), B::f() failed to compile because it cannot find the function A::f(int). **The question is WHY?**

Using the full name (obviously helps... void f(){ A::f(5); }). But what really makes it all weird is that void f(){ g(5); } works!

I do understand that it is because f() is implemented in both A and B, but why the compiler cannot understand on its own that the method is at class A?

Thanks!

p.s. My **guess** is that maybe f() is implemented not only in A but maybe in A's base class, so in cases like these the compiler can't really know, but as I wrote, I'm just guessing...

Comment: That's the way unqualified name lookup works: it starts from the current scope, searches upwards and outwards, and stops as soon as it finds the name. Thus name lookup for `f` searches class `B`, finds a number of declarations there, and never gets to `A`. Then overload resolution is performed on whatever was found; in this case, it fails. `g` is not found in `B`, so the lookup proceeds to search `A`. To make it work, add `using A::f;` inside the definition of `B` - that brings all things named `f` from `A` into `B`'s scope.

Comment: So it looks up at B, doesn't find, why doesn't it continue to A? Simply a definition? Or is there a real problem?

Comment: It stops as soon as it finds a matching name.

Comment: It does find. There are in fact declarations of name `f` in class `B`. It is only later that the compiler determines that none of them are suitable for the call. Name lookup happens first; then overload resolution (on functions that the lookup found); and finally access check (on the function that overload resolution picked).

Comment: You can do:  `using A::f` in class B and it'll find it.

Comment: Okay, but I got a "technical" answer, but if I "fix" the compiler to look in a smarter way, it will work, right?
But the more I think about it, it seems like the compiler cannot solve it because it doesn't have enough information. By calling f(), it doesn't know which f() because of other base classes (could be ambiguous, and that is the error I was looking for!). It even makes more sense with Brandon's comment about using which tells the compiler where to look.

Sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler looks for the function by name first, ignoring the arguments. So it sees `B::f()` and then starts trying to match arguments. Since `B::f()` takes no arguments the compiler throws an error. With the call to `g()` there is no match in `B` so the compiler looks in `A` and finds it.